# redundant ICommand class for wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm still learning about wpf, however I'm familiar withe how to setup mvvm in wpf c#. However when it comes to the ICommand/RelayCommand stuff, its a bit of a confusing area for me. Over the past few months I've compiled a few implementations of the ICommand classes in order to create my tools. However I'm at the point now where I've read a few articles and I've looked at the code long enough, I'm looking for someone to help me out and put into simple terms what is going on here and if so, how can I combine/clean up these classes. At the moment the code seems redundant and I'm not sure how to go about optimizing it. Hope this isn't asking for to much. Thanks.

The two important things I want to maintain in this, is the ability to pass arguments to the commands as seen in this first usage example of RelayCommand. Secondly the ability to enable/disable a command as seen in the second command.

So in my tool i have this helper class. 
1. I don't get the differences of use between the two classes inside this RelayCommand.cs. There is a public and an internal class.
2. Is there a need for both or can they be combine?
**RelayCommand.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1.Helper
{
    public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<T> execute;
        private readonly Predicate<T> canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return canExecute == null || canExecute((T)parameter);
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute((T)parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
    }

    // added
    internal class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of me using the **RelayCommand.cs** in my class object called Customer.cs

```
private ICommand addNewLicense_Command;
public ICommand AddNewLicense_Command
{
    get
    {
        return addNewLicense_Command ?? (addNewLicense_Command = new RelayCommand<Customer>(n =>
        {
            AddNewLicense_Execute(n);
        }));
    }
}
```

So then in my MainViewModel.cs i have another **ICommand Class** in the same project my Helper class mentioned above is part of. Is this class necessary? It seems so similar to the RelayCommand class.

```
public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private bool _canExecute;
    public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

An example of me using **CommandHandler** in my MainViewModel.cs

```
private ICommand addNewUser_Command;
public ICommand AddNewUser_Command
{
    get
    {
        return addNewUser_Command ?? (addNewUser_Command = new CommandHandler(() => AddNewUser_Execute(), true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just keep one class relay command. No need to keep other classes. Keeping it internal or public is up to your usage pattern. If you want to keep relay command in different assembly keep it public and if it is in same assembly where VMs are present make it internal

Comment: @SatyakiChatterjee in the RelayCommand.cs whats the difference between the two classes inside the code block? I noticed one class ends with <T> and the other doesn't. Whats the benefits of one over the other? Am I find to omit one and just keep the other? Lastly, whichever one i decide to keep, how can i use it and control it being enabled or disabled using the can execute.

Comment: Then class ends with <T> is generic class and one that ends with object is not generic. Better you use the class with <T>. With T you can use any type which makes your class more generic. But with object you can only use object. I would request you to take a look on the c# generics.. Anyway go with <T> one

Comment: What do you mean i can only use object? Do you mean every team i use a relay command i have to pass it an object? Even if i don't need to?

Comment: Action<T> points to a method where return type is void and accepts one parameter. T means generic type. You can pass string,Object, custom class and even null ( if you don't need any param for a particular case). Please check the documentation on generics, Action and Predicate

Comment: i will read more on that in the morning its getting late. Would you at least be able to show how i would use the <T> method and pass the second argument in order to set a method 'can execute' to true or false

Comment: This might be better on Code Review . Stack Exchange.  Wishing you well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a library like MVVM Lite then it will provide the RelayCommand implementations for you. Either way use the non-generic when you don't need a parameter passed in e.g. an "Ok" button:

```
public ICommand OkCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(Ok); } }
protected virtual void Ok()
{
    // ... do something ...
}
```

The associated XAML is something like:

```
<Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding OkCommand}" IsDefault="True" />
```

Use the generic when you want to pass a parameter:

```
public ICommand OpenClientCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<Client>(OnOpenClient); } }
private void OnOpenClient(Client client)
{
    // ... do something with client ...
}
```

In this case you need to pass in a Client object via the command parameter:

```
<Button Content="Open" Command="{Binding OpenClientCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedClient}"/>
```

Passing parameters is also handy when used with event triggers, e.g. you can add something like this to intercept your MainWindow's Closing event:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This trigger passes the message arguments into your handler which gives you the opportunity to cancel it in the event that the user hasn't saved their changes:

```
public ICommand ClosingCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(OnClosing); } }
private void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
{
    if (!PromptUserForClose())
        args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The RelayCommand you have is all you need. If you want to disable the command you can pass a method in the constructor do do so:

```
return addNewLicense_Command ?? (addNewLicense_Command = new RelayCommand<Customer>(n =>
    {
        AddNewLicense_Execute(n);
    },AllowAddNeLicense));

...

bool AllowAddNewLicense() 
{
    return _allowAddEnabled;
}
```

The second class called CommandHandler is just another implementation of ICommand. The difference is that you can pass the "enabled" boolean inside the constructor, which means it will remain the same unless you create a new instance of it. While in the RelayCommand you can pass a function that gets executed everytime* so you can influence the outcome.